# Floating point exception(core dumped) very wierd

Tags: c++

I know this has already been asked but I haven't found and answer.
This is my code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int a[510];

int main()
{
    int n, p;
    bool rez;
    while(1)
    {
        p = 0;
        rez = 1;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n == -1) break;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        // printf("a");
        for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if((a[i]+p)%i)
            {
                rez = 0;
                break;
            }
            p++;
        }
        if(rez) printf("S\n");
        else printf("N\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

All test cases work fine except test case:
4
1 1 3 0
but
4
1 0 3 1
works.
Also in problematic test case I have inserted printf("a");
but program doesn't print it which indicates that the problem occurs before that line. However, if I remove the rest of the code everything works OK.

Comment: Check that `i` doesn't become zero here `if((a[i]+p)%i)`.

Comment: Try stepping through in a debugger. There is something odd going on. You have no floating point at all

Comment: Please add a proper description of what your code is supposed to do, and what the problematic input was. I don't know what you mean with "test case 4 1 1 3 0". Is that the number you entered, including the spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A floating point exception is reported not only for floating-point errors, but also for an integer division by 0, including taking the modulus with respect to 0 (as πάντα-ῥεῖ says in the first comment). Your `i` loop does iterate down to zero. Once this happens -- i.e. when the `break` statement didn't trigger for previous values of `i` -- you'll see the floating-point exception.

Comment: Yeah, it was late in night when I posted it so I haven't noticed it then, but it is still weird why oder test cases executed normally